# Navigation Drawer implements Master/Detail with customadapter

Tags: android, master-detail, navigation-drawer

Good day sorry for bothering you but I would like to ask, 'cause I'm having a hard time, on understanding the implementation of master/detail inside navigation drawer fragment and on how to implement master/detail flow inside a fragment(since I am using a navigation drawer).

I want to implement it(master/detail layout) when I click an item in one of my navigation drawer items.

I tried [this](https://inducesmile.com/android/how-to-combine-android-navigation-drawer-and-master-detail-flow-in-android/) but I'm stuck in the adapter cause I have my own arraylist of data and I tried to search other resources about this but unfortunately some are outdated.

**EDIT:**
Is there any suggestion on how to implement a masterdetail layout inside a navigation drawer activity? Please, please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: android studio provides built in activity for master detail flow

Comment: Add your code, where u have stucked?

Comment: @VivekMishra yes I created one but how will I convert its mainactivity into a fragment? cause I want to implement it inside my navigation drawer activity.

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha sorry, what I mean is I'm stuck in modifying the recyclerviewadapter part of the tutorial I mentioned.

Comment: add your code. Can't determine from tutorial where you are stuck and what are you doing that you got stuck